# Why remaining Adafruit FT232H GPIO pins are going to reset when I set one pin?

Tags: python, embedded, gpio

I am working on Adafruit FT232H with UBUNTU gateway. I need to control the GPIO pins one by one. I wrote a script in python to control the GPIO pins. But when I turn on GPIO pin 9, GPIO pin 8 turns off automatically which was previously turned ON unlike Raspberry Pi GPIO pins. As I knew, the state of previous pins should remains unchangeable until we explicitly change it from LOW to HIGH or vice versa. I have little knowledge on python and the Adafruit datasheet, so could you please suggest me what I done wrong in below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO
import Adafruit_GPIO.FT232H as FT232H
FT232H.use_FT232H()
ft232h = FT232H.FT232H()
chno = int(sys.argv[1]) #channel(8-15) number passed as argument
status = int(sys.argv[2]) #status(LOW/HIGH or 0/1) passed as argument
ft232h.setup(chno,GPIO.OUT)
if (status == 0):
      ft232h.output(chno, GPIO.LOW)
if (status == 1):
      ft232h.output(chno, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: Maybe when you're starting the device, it sets all the outputs to 'low', so when you rerun the script, it'll reset the pins to the default value. I guess you should change the outputs without restarting your script.

Comment: Thanks tglaria. But the problem is not that.For example, if pin 9 is set to HIGH by explicitly, that means I turned on LED 9 and now I want to turn on another LED pin 10, so I have to set pin 10 to HIGH explicitly but the problem is now, pin 9 is set to LOW automatically when I set pin 10 to high. Simply, for each execution, only .current states going to set and all previous states are reset to LOW implicitly.

Comment: Well, how are you setting each pin?
From the python interpretter?

Comment: yes. Through python interpreter I am setting gpio pins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try with this code:

```
ft232h.setup(9,GPIO.OUT)
ft232h.setup(10,GPIO.OUT)
ft232h.output(9, GPIO.HIGH)
ft232h.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Do you have both pins high?

And with the following code?

```
ft232h.setup(9,GPIO.OUT)
ft232h.output(9, GPIO.HIGH)
ft232h.setup(10,GPIO.OUT)
ft232h.output(10, GPIO.HIGH)
```

Comment: Yes tglaria. I tried similar code as above to set multiple pins at a time. Then it able to turn on multiple in single shot, but when I am trying to set ON one more pin, all previous gets off.

Comment: No idea then, I guess you'll have to contact with the developper of the device and/or check the soruce code, find the line that makes the change and do your own API.